# How to get the JSON/array value property name for a field instance?

Tags: 8, entities

Given a `Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition`  how do you get whether the value is stored by `target_id`, or `value` or `uri` or `color` or ....

it seems `getMainPropertyName()` is what i'm looking, for but it returns `null` for the majority of fields. in my case it's only returning target_id or value for for created, status, and entity_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested using a variety of field types, and it seems to work OK for me. Here's the code I used for testing:

```
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);

print $node->get('field_test')->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getMainPropertyName();
print $node->get('field_test_image')->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getMainPropertyName();
print $node->get('field_test_link')->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getMainPropertyName();
print $node->get('field_test_email')->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getMainPropertyName();
```

This returns value, target_id, uri and value as one would have expected. What kind of fields are giving you trouble? How do you get you `BaseFieldDefinition` class? What kind of entity are they connected to?

I notice that the Views way of getting the property name is also pretty pragmatic:

```
// EntityField.php line 1111
if ($main_property_name = $field_item->mainPropertyName()) {
  $values[] = $field_item->{$main_property_name};
}
else {
  $values[] = $field_item->value;
}
```

Clearly it's not completely unexpected to have this method return `null`.

Comment: perfect. I was using executing the method on `getFieldDefinition()` and not `getFieldStorageDefinition()`

Answer (score 2):

This code works for getting the main property name of the field for a particular content type

```
$entityFieldManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
$fields = $entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'article');
foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_definition) {
  if (!empty($field_definition->getTargetBundle())) {            
    $storage[$field_name]['storage_value'] = $field_definition->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getMainPropertyName();               
  }
}
```